# Rails stop executing function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webbrowser-control, webrick

I have a method called send_email_to_all.
Now, Suppose a user press "send email" button, the above function sends an email to 100 persons. But it takes so much time to execute the above send_email_to_all method.
But if User wants to stop this method while executing, the user will press stop button which is provided by every web browser at the top.
Now the problem is though user had pressed stop, the WEBrick doesn't stop executing the function.
What is solution?

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be letting Rails process that many emails through a single web request. You should provide some sort of background process to manage their delivery.

[Railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=32) covers several popular background workers and the examples typically demonstrate how to process email delivery.

Comment: I just gave an example of sending Email.
There might be any other function which takes sometime to execute.
And while executing if user stops the request, then that method should be stopped at server.